# Emberjs Displaying Associative Data Within Parent Model Template

Tags: ember.js, associations, ember-data

I've hit a snag in my Ember application that I've been trying to break free from. I have a two models like below:

```
App.UserModel = DS.Model.extend({
  ../
  actions: DS.hasMany('action')
});
```

and

```
App.ActionModel = DS.Model.extend({
  ../
  user: DS.belongsTo('user')
});
```

My route for viewing a user profile is as follows:

```
App.UsersProfileRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.get('store').find('user', params.user_id);
  }
});
```

Which grabs the following structure from the server:

```
{
  user: {
    action_ids: [1, 2, 3]
  },
  actions: [{
    id: 1,
    type: "Problem"
  },{
    id: 2,
    type: "Problem"
  },{
    id: 3,
    type: "Problem"
  }]
}
```

This loads up the store properly according to Ember's Chrome Extension. However when I try and access the association data in a template like so:

```
<h2>Actions</h2>
<div class="container">
  {{#each actions}}
    you have action
  {{else}}
    You don't have actions
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

It appears that the actions association is empty or null as it doesn't pass the #each check even with the Ember Store showing the proper stored information.

I've tried a few things with the template like {{#each action in model.actions}} etc, but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
user: {
  action_ids: [1, 2, 3]
},
```

should be

```
user: {
  actions: [1, 2, 3]
},
```

Comment: When utilizing the RESTAdapter with EmberData and not the FIXTUREAdapter?

Comment: in ED 1.0 beta and newer

Comment: Wow, I have spent way too much time for it to be so simple... GAH... it worked though. Thanks for the help.